# CiviMobile server connection problem

Tags: civimobile

My CiviCRM install on the WP. And I installed the CiviMobileAPI(v5.0.0).

I succeeded login from iPhone. but I try to use same URL to login from Android, I get error that says "can't connect to the server. Check the CiviCRM site URL or internet connect"

Not sure what else to try here, does any one have any insights? I'm sure I've put in my correct credentials.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Go to Resource URL page and click on '?' and see if civicrm.root and cms.root variables are set correctly, if not than you may need to update civicrm.settings.php to fix it.